# Locate WPF Command Binding Source

Tags: c#, wpf, command, visual-studio-2022

How do I locate the source code of a WPF command binding when it's executed (using C# in Visual Studio 2022 Community edition)?

For example, if I issue a cut, paste, undo or redo command in a grid, which is embedded fairly deeply in the visual tree, somewhere in the WPF tree there may be a command binding hierarchy with associated code-behind command handler methods CanExecuteHandler() and ExecuteHandler(). How do I track down this code (back through the hierarchy)?

As a starting point I've tried examining the Default->CommandBindings property in Live Property Explorer for the grid but it is blank.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if VS toolset can locate them, but full-text search in project (or solution) will find all "ExecuteHandler" usages, and then you can set breakpoints in likely candidates

Comment: For paste to have any effect you need a control it has meaning to. That decides how to implement the command. A richtext editor kiinda control is going to insert into it's document what's in the clipboard at the carat

Comment: Or you can use some code methods to query the data source when viewing the data source. For example, if I am using ADO.NET, I can use SqlDataReader to obtain data source information.